# Flutter Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter

### Steps to Reproduce

Hello guys, I am currently working on an application in which I use firebase. Up to now everything worked as expected but from the moment I added the plugin firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.0.1+3  I had as error:

### Logs

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.16.
  1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: io.grpc:grpc-android:1.16.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core@[1.16.1], but grpc-core version was 1.21.0.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_in_app_messaging' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmes
  saging-display@18.0.2
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@19.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-okhttp@1.21.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display@18.0.2
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'cloud_firestore' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@19.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-android@1.16.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto io.grpc:grpc-core@1.21.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging@18.0.2

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 43s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

### FLUTTER ANALYSE

> Running "flutter pub get" in niochi...
>   35,3s Analyzing niochi... No issues found! (ran in 2.4s)

### FLUTTER DOCTOR

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17134.1], locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at D:\Dev\FLUTTER\flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (4 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Dev\SDK1\SDK1
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] VS Code (version 1.37.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Orion WAMBERT\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.3.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

### Pubspec

```
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+1
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9
  firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.0.1+3
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.5
  flutter_crashlytics: ^1.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.6
```